# Sending an on-the-fly created QR Code UIImage by AirDrop fails

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, qr-code, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am creating a QR Code on the fly and storing it as UIImage. Now I want to be able to send it using the UIActivityViewController but somehow it fails:

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

And then I am calling the function and store it as UIImage:

```
let image = generateQRCode(from: "Create my Code")
imgQRCode.image = image
```

The export button uses the following action:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

        let objectsToShare = [imgQRCode.image!] as [AnyObject]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

After choosing to send via AirDrop to my Mac the app crashes

```
2016-11-05 23:29:15.912242 Ordnung[3945:888442] CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Nov  5 23:29:15  Ordnung[3945] : CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

```
2016-11-05 23:29:15.912396 Ordnung[3945:888442] CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov  5 23:29:15  Ordnung[3945] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2016-11-05 23:29:15.912584 Ordnung[3945:888442] CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov  5 23:29:15  Ordnung[3945] <Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2016-11-05 23:29:15.912692 Ordnung[3945:888442] CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov  5 23:29:15  Ordnung[3945] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
2016-11-05 23:29:15.927580 Ordnung[3945:888442] [AirDrop] Sender kSFOperationEventErrorOccured {
    Error = "Error Domain=SFOperation Code=-5 \"Die \U00dcbertragung ist fehlgeschlagen, da du eine ung\U00fcltige Datei senden wolltest.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Die \U00dcbertragung ist fehlgeschlagen, da du eine ung\U00fcltige Datei senden wolltest.}";
    SessionID = 76FBE80074FC;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to get this done?

Cheers Maik

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems I need to provide the image in a slightly different way, so altering the QR code generation this way solves the problem by creating a CGImage before creating the UIImage:

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        let upScaledImage = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform)


        let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(upScaledImage!,
                                              from: upScaledImage!.extent)
        let qrcodeImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
        return qrcodeImage
    }
    return nil
}
```

**For Swift 4.2**

```
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let ciContext = CIContext()
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
        let upScaledImage = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform)

        let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(upScaledImage!, from: upScaledImage!.extent)
        let qrcodeImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
        return qrcodeImage
    }
    return nil
}
```

And additionally you should use a png or jpg representation of the image:

```
func share() {
    let png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(qrcodeImage)
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [png!], applicationActivities: [])
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: After searching for days, this is the solution which finally worked for me. In all other solutions you can only see the generate image on the screen but cannot save it as a file which I was trying to do.